# Windows Embedded Standard 7 thin client - copying files over the network with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, windows-embedded

Is this possible to copy files from a network location with a batch file over to a thin client running Windows Embedded Standard 7.

COPY command won't work, and when I try to navigate to a network location in a Windows Explorer, I get prompted to enter my user name and password.

I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: You're admin on the local host, but are you a domain admin? Or, if in a workgroup, do both local and target computer have same admin username and password? If not, then it won't work.

Comment: Can you put your comment as answer? I have since understood what the issue is and it's pretty much what you described...basically, one needs to login to the server using net use command.

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating to another Windows host to copy files over RPC (i.e., standard method to browse files over network), you need sufficient rights. There are three authentication scenarios to describe the permissions needed:

1) If both computers are in the same workgroup, then the username and password on both local and remote hosts need to be the same.

2) If both computers are on the same - or mutually trusting - domains, then your account likely needs to be an administrator on the remote host.

3) If not an admin on the remote host, then it needs to have the right permissions to the designated folder and share.